# Designating composite primary key as a foreign key on supabase

Tags: supabase

[image]
This is basic diagram for what I am trying to make.

I am trying to make two public DBs on supabase, `category` and `item`.
Both `category` and `item` is accessed by its own user, and `item` will always have one `category` that it belongs.

So I first created `category` with two columns, `user_id [uuid/FK]` and `category_id[int8]` as a composite primary key. It worked well.

But then I tried to create `item` with three columnns, `user_id [uuid/FK]` and `item_id[int8]` as a composite key and `category_id[int8/FK]` as foreign key. But it fails to create such table, because `category_id` column itself is not a unique column.

But creating `category_user_id [uuid/FK]` seems unnecessary, so I was wondering how can I tell supabase that `user_id [uuid/FK]` is also used as a foreign key for `category_id`.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Because `item` has `user_id`, you don't need the `user_id` on `category` table. Also you don't need to create a composite key of `category_id` and `user_id` on your `item` table since multiple items can be created by the same user with the same category.

> But creating category_user_id [uuid/FK] seems unnecessary, so I was wondering how can I tell supabase that user_id [uuid/FK] is also used as a foreign key for category_id.

Just by creating a foreign key on `item` table for `users` table, and a foreign key on `category` table for `item` table, Supabase knows that `users` is associated to `cateogry`. No need to do anything further.